# ./Pep8: error while loading shared libraries: libQtWebKit.so.4 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: shared-libraries, ubuntu-20.04, pep8-assembly

I have to install PEP/8 on my Ubuntu 20.04 for my assembly course, but when I try to run the file:

`./Pep8`

I have this error:

`./Pep8: error while loading shared libraries: libQtWebKit.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

But, I see the library in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/".

But I think that the program was made with 32bits architecture:

`file Pep8`

`Pep8: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, BuildID[sha1]=59393bb4f063551ac708a7690b8cb2fce1121ded, with debug_info, not stripped`

I'm not sure about what I have to do to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I tried installing libqtcore4 and libqtwebkit4 from this ppa: `ppa:rock-core/qt4`, but it doesn't solve my problem. Finally, I just compile the Terminal version from the source code. You can find it [here](http://computersystemsbook.com/go/pep-8-terminal-simul-and-assembler/).

```sh
# assuming you're in the binaries directories
./asem8 your_pep_code.pep
# You start the emulator,
# load the object file
# and execute it
./pep8
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the qtwebkit package:

yum provides */libQtWebKit.so.4